# Thread-safe LRU cache in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, cache

I've written a simple LRU cache class and I am trying to make it thread-safe. My thoughts are that I just need to wrap the code that updates the ordered dict in a lock so that if any thread is writing to the ordered dict, all other writes/reads need to wait. Is that correct?

Also, what is the best way to test that something is thread-safe?

```
import threading
from collections import OrderedDict

class Cache:
  def __init__(self, capacity):
    self._count = 0
    self._capacity = capacity
    self._store = OrderedDict()
    self._lock = threading.Lock()
    
  def count(self):
    return self._count

  def capacity(self):
    return self._capacity

  def get(self, key):
    if key in self._store:
      self._store.move_to_end(key)
    return self._store[key]

  def set(self, key, value):
    with self._lock: # this was the only place i thought that needed locking
      if key not in self._store:
        if self._count >= self._capacity:
          self._store.popitem(last=False)
          self._count -= 1
        self._store[key] = value
        self._count += 1
      else:
        self._store[key] = value
        self._store.move_to_end(key)

  def containsKey(self, key):
    return key in self._store
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I changed the title so that it describes what the code does per [site goals](/questions/how-to-ask): "*State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it.*". Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `self._store` isn't thread-safe, because we are only locking its writers.  We need to ensure that readers don't see it in an inconsistent state, too.

Comment: Thanks Toby!! So you're saying that it's possible that 1 thread may be writing, but since I'm not locking any reads, it's possible for another thread to get an older value. So say the cache has v1. A write happens at t2 for value v2, but a read could potentially happen at t3 that still gets v1?

Comment: I guess i could test it, i just learned how to create threads! :) Sounds like I could make a write take long while a read thread goes and see what I'm getting back.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that one thread could be in `get()` while another is in `set()`, and that would be bad, since `get()` doesn't take the lock.  Automatically testing for race conditions is hard; I don't know of any means other than hammering the code with many threads and checking for inconsistencies - but that's only a stochastic approach, and it can't prove the code correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced that `key in self._store` is not a thread-safe way to check if a key exists in a dictionary, even when wrapped in a `with lock`.

Replacing `key in self._store` with `key in self._store.keys()`, and wrapping all accessors and setters on `self._store` with `with self._lock` should be sufficient.